# Laravel homestead after.sh unable to auto setup custom configuration

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, vagrant, homestead

I`m using laravel/homestead package and im trying tu set some configuration on "after.sh" file, but with no success.

After run the command "vagrant up" i want to make the followings statments:

1- Install sshpass dependency without asking (y/n)

```
sudo apt-get -y install sshpass
```

2- Create a ssh key without asking (file/password)

```
ssh-keygen -b 2048 -f ~/.ssh/mykeyname-t rsa -N ''
```

3- Copy the ssh id to domain without asking (password)

```
sshpass -p mypassword ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/mykeyname user@domain
```

And when vagrant is up i want to be able to connect with comand:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey user@domain
```

If all those thing i do it manually it works properly, but i want to know if is possible to create script in "after.sh" to automate it and ready to use when machine is deployed.

I tryied to write those lines on "after.sh" but it is not ready to use when machine is deployed.

It seems to work just to step 2 and never work on step 3.
Can anyone help me, or tell me if this can be done?

Thanks for awnsers, and sorry my english.

Comment: Vagrant up only brings up the machine. Why should it execute the SSH command?

Comment: Hi, the package laravel/homestead has an script called "after.sh" that is executed after the machine is deployed via "vagrant up" or "vagrant provision" is there where im trying to make some extra customization of the box. Thanks for anwser.

Answer (score 0):

i just find the answer.

Between step 2 and 3, creating sshkey and copysshid i need to first add the domain to known_hosts with the following command

```
ssh-keyscan domain>> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

And then after deploy machine via vagrant up i was able to login shh without password with the following command:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey user@domain
```

Thanks everyone.